Vue I18n with variables
In vue2 I used to be able to have variables in my json translation file like this:
"info": "Email: <a href=\"mailto:@:contact-details.email\">@:contact-details.email</a>"

And then in the same file I defined:
"contact-details": {
      "phone": "123456789",
      "email": "email@email.com"
}

I then use it in a component like this:
$t('info')

However, If I try to use this in Vue3 it doesn't work. I get "Email: " but no email after that on the screen. It seems like the variable thing doesn't work in vue3 anymore? How can I make it work in Vue3?

For anyone looking for answer to this there is a space missing in below between email and " which made it interpret it wrong. So instead of:
"info": "Email: <a href=\"mailto:@:contact-details.email\">@:contact-details.email</a>"

It needs to be:
"info": "Email: <a href=\"mailto:@:contact-details.email \">@:contact-details.email</a>"

The first one worked in Vue2 but not in Vue3 which is a bit strange.
